# animating object from low poly to higher poly

Tags: animation

Absolute beginner here. So thank you.

My objective is to (animate) mimic growth of a model from a simple object with few polygons to a more complex object with more polygons.

Example: A simple cube becoming a cube with that is elongated with a higher polygon count and detail.

Short of building separate, successive models for each frame to be rendered to a timeline (which would be doable but extremely tedious), is there a more efficient workflow?

Comment: A cube? How does a cube benefit from having more polygons? Could you clarify how that should look like?

Comment: The cube was an example. The objective is to mimic a time-lapse of a single plant growing from seedling to maturity. The polys and details change as the plant matures. So...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Christopher's answer works if you are just looking animate it to be more smooth over time. however, if you want more control over the final model, I would work backwards and animate a Decimate modifier.

Start with a high poly count object, then give it a decimate modifier. Keyframe it at a very low ratio at the start, and then a ratio of 1 at the end to get the original object back. Then the object will build up more triangles over time:

[image: result]

Comment: The *Weld* modifier with an animated *Distance* value works also very well.

Comment: @Blunder: Weld gives strange artifacts sometimes: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFLnS.png

Comment: I did think about working backwards. So yes, thank you for that idea.

Answer (score 6):

One way you could do it is by adding keyframes to a *Subdivison Surface* modifier.

[image: Kf]

[image: Morph]

NOTE - Make sure to change (and keyframe) the subdivision level for the render as well as the viewport (not pictured) - I just noticed I forgot to do it in the .gif

EDIT - Here's a second example that better illustrates what the OP is looking for. A bevel modifier is used to preserve the cube "shape" while also adding to the resolution in the end. This also gives the subdivision surface modifier "something more to do" to add to the effect. In the example below, it looks "smoother" if I just play the animation instead of dragging the slider across, but that doesn't show the modifier values changing in real time - I thought that was more important to convey then the smoothness, but fret not - I can assure you the interpolation is smooth ;)

[image: Morph3]

The keyframes (as I remember) are this:

```
Frame 0 - Bevel: Amount 0.5, Segments 2 - SubDiv: Levels 0
Frame 25 - Bevel: Amount 0.25, Segments 2 - SubDiv: Levels 2 - Scale on Y by 2 and keyframe scale
Frame 50 - Bevel: Amount 0.1, Segments 3 - SubDiv: Levels 4 - Scale on Y by 1.5 and keyframe scale
```

Comment: Adding a subdivision surface if you don't already have one will change the object's shape, doesn't it?

Comment: It depends on the topology - there will be some change to the model, yes, but not if set to 0 subdivisions for the "starting point". I assume that if the goal is to morph the object to "high poly", a subdivision surface will be necessary at some point, and since the number of subdivisions is the keyframe-able property, it makes sense to have it there from the beginning and just "up" it as time goes on. You are correct, though, this will not accommodate _all_ model topology types - just _one_ way of doing it.

Comment: OP mentions "cube" as his example. It you add a subsurf onto a cube, it's not a "cube with many vertices"

Comment: The cube was an example. I'm looking to mimic an accurate time-lapse of plant growth.